# CBMC Model Checking

Tags: c, cbmc

I'm trying to constraint the table `b[4][4]` such that only those places which have `i>=j` and satisfying the condition that `(stored[i] & stored[j]) == stored[i]` be 1, and the rest be 0.

Why this is not working?

```
void main(){
  unsigned int i = 0  , j = 0; 
  _Bool b[4][4];
  bitvector stored[4] = {111,001,010,000};
  for(i=0;i<4;i++){
     for(j=0;j<4;j++){
      __CPROVER_assume( !(b[i][j]) || ((i>=j) && (stored[i] & stored[j] == stored[i])));  
      }
   }
```

CProver assume trying to get an effect that `b[i][j] == 1` should imply `stored[i]& stored[j] == stored[i]`. 
But the output doesn't have this effect. What's the problem? I'm new to CBMC and to C also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that values in `bitvector stored[4] = {111,001,010,000};` are in base 10.

Do you mean base 2 `{0b111,0b001,0b010,0b000}`?

Comment: Thanks. Added that. But also missed  a bracket.  ( (stored[i] & stored[j]) == stored[i] ) rather than (stored[i] & stored[j] == stored[i])

Comment: Thanks again revisiting and you saved my lot of time.